# How to open a *.ipynb file editor through vscode extension API?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I open an existing *.ipynb file with a Jupyter Notebook editor from the file's url in a VSCode extension through VSCode extension APIs?

There is a `vscode.window.showTextDocument` API. Are there any equivalent APIs for notebook files like `showNotebookDocument`?

For example

```js
const filePath = 'path/to/notebook.ipynb';
vscode.workspace.openNotebookDocument(vscode.Uri.file(filePath)).then((doc) => {
    vscode.window.showNotebookDocument(doc);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just found my answer

```js
vscode.commands.executeCommand("vscode.openWith", vscode.Uri.file(filePath), 'jupyter-notebook');
```